# How to minimize/fix the firefox browser window with selenium 2.0 standalone and in a perl script

Tags: perl, firefox, selenium-server

I use selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar as selenium server and perl script (with [Test::WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium)) to do tests. Then selenium test starts and Firefox windows are opening. I'd like to reduce then to the smallest window as possible.

I'm starting selenium by using the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate ./selenium.ff.profil
```

and try to change the size in the profile with addons, but it doesn't work. The windows are resized.

Any idea how to fix the Firefox window size or reduce it with perl ?